# Dependency Injection in XPCOM

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, firefox-addon, xpcom

One of my XPCOM components make use of other XPCOM components. As I was testing it, I found it cumbersome cos of the dependencies. Then I thought of using Dependency Injection to pass in the other components in my constructor. I wasn't successful. Is it possible to pass in references of other components into your constructor?

```
 var _foo = Components.classes["@foo.com/foo;1"].createInstance(bar);
 this.foo = _foo.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.IFoo);
```

For example, foo component needs bar. Can I pass in bar via foo's constructor? I tried the above but it didn't work.

Zan

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to pass in references of other components into your constructor?

No. The parameter to `createInstance` is an interface; `.createInstance(interface)` is a shortcut for `.createInstance().QueryInterface(interface)`.

The answer to your problem lies in the area you didn't describe in the question - most likely you don't need to access the other component from your "constructor" or you stumbled on a problem you could fix, but instead "cumbersome cos of the dependencies" and moved on.